# Как не показывать страницу до выполнения скрипта

Tags: javascript

Хочу JavaScript'ом сделать замену содержимого блоков. Нужно все это сделать так чтобы пользователь не видел как прыгает контент.

Замену произвожу таким кодом:

```
document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML="newtext";
```

В итоге загружается страница с исходным контентом, и только потом заменяется на мой  текст.

Каким образом не показывать страницу покуда не выполниться мой код замены содержимого?

Answer (score 0):

```
<span id="myspan" style="visibility:hidden">old text</span>

document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML = "new text";
document.getElementById("myspan").style.visbility = "visible";
```

Comment: хмм, да, как вариант. а нет более "крутого" решения?